# Rails 5 Eager load and then find_by

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, eager-loading

I have three models as follows:

```
class Parent < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :children
  has_many :assets
end

class Child < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :parent
end

class Asset < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :parent
end
```

Now I need to find out the assets that belong to a child through parent. And "Asset" has asset_type column. So I need to do something like this

```
Parent.first.children.each do |child|
  child.parent.assets.find_by(asset_type: "first").asset_value
end
```

How can I do this avoiding N+1 queries?

rails: 5.1.6

ruby: 2.3.4

Comment: I don't think you have an N+1 problem in that query, unless you want to do something like `Child.each do |child|`

Comment: Yes, you are right. I need to iterate the children. Sorry I missed it. Edited the post. Thanks

Comment: Maybe it's just the example, but I don't understand why you are saying `Parent.first.children` and then `child.parent.assets`.  Since a child only has one parent, then you should just say `Parent.first.assets.find_by(asset_type: 'first').asset_value`

Comment: @KPheasey I'm guessing it's a toy example, and this idea needs to be applied to a collection of `parent`s, and that more needs to be done per child-assets than is being displayed here. Good to keep the noise out of the question IMO.

Comment: Yes, this is just an example. Real scenario is more complex. Child has STI.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First issue is that adding a `find_by` will *always* execute another query no matter what you have preloaded (at least as of Rails 4, I doubt it has changed though). This is because `find_by` is implemented to generate more SQL. If you want to preload, you can use `find` instead, which is fine as long as there aren't a ridiculous number of assets per parent, but bad if there are lots and lots of assets and/or they are large objects that would take up a ton of memory (see note below for alt solution).

You can preload assets like this:

```
parent.children.preload(:parent => :assets) each do |child|
# Will not execute another query
child.parent.assets.find{ |asset| asset.asset_type == "first" }
```

Alternatively, you can declare a `has_many :through` association:

```
class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent
  has_many :assets, through: :parent
  ...
end
```

Then you can simply

```
parent.children.preload(:assets).each do |child|
# Will not execute another query
child.assets.find { |asset| asset.asset_type == "first" }
```

---

If you want to execute the find in the db layer and not in ruby, you can define a scoped association:

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :first_asset, ->{ where asset_type: "first" }
  ...
end
```

This way you can `preload(:parent => :first_asset)` instead.

Comment: You are a hero. This idea helped me to minimise the query time. Thanks