# Ruby on Rails Eager loading with find_by

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, eager-loading

I tried to make a movie app and stuck with eager loading with find_by.

I found a similar case in another StackOverflow Q&A as below, but it was not enough for the case of mine.

[Rails 5 Eager load and then find_by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52762015/rails-5-eager-load-and-then-find-by)

I have 2 join table records, WatchList(MoviesUser) and Rating. I couldn't use "has_many :users, through: :ratings" to ratings because there was already MoviesUser relation.

```
class Movie < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_many :ratings
end
```

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :movies
  has_many :ratings
end
```

```
class MoviesUser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :movie
  belongs_to :user
end
```

```
class Rating < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :movie
  belongs_to :user
end
```

How can I avoid N+1 queries as below?

I found out that "movie.users.find_by_id" has been solved at the following code(Thanks to the previous StackOverflow Q&A mentioned above), but I couldn't solve "movie.ratings.find_by_id".

```
@movies = Movie.joins(:ratings).where(ratings: {user_id: current_user.id}).includes(:ratings).includes(:users)
@watchlist_addeds = {}
@movie_rating_current_user = {}

@movies.preload(:users).each do |movie|
    @watchlist_addeds[movie.id] = movie.users.find_by_id(current_user.id) ? true : false
    @movie_rating_current_user[movie.id] = movie.ratings.find_by(user_id: current_user.id).rating_value
end
```

If I change this code to as below, it seems to be solved, but I am not sure if it is the right answer when there are ridiculous numbers of ratings for each movie.

```
@movie_rating_current_user[movie.id] = movie.ratings.filter {|rating| rating.user_id == current_user.id}[0].rating_value
```

Comment: Is the format of the `@watchlist_addeds` and `@movie_rating_current_user` collections matter? And can you describe  how do you plan to use this collections?
I see some variants to simplify this code.

Answer (score 1):

You already have a where condition in your movies query that will remove all ratings not belonging to the current user. In the each, `movie.ratings` will only contain ratings belonging to the current user.

Instead of `find_by` or `filter` you should be able to just call `first`, though it will do the same and be about as fast as your filter solution.